# 2012 R2 - Dell 220 Becomes Unresponsive

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dell-poweredge

We have a branch location running a MSSQL database. The server will become unresponsive on certain Tuesday nights. I've never seen anything quite like it. We monitor with PRTG and the first thing to go is RDP. Then later that night ping and the database monitors will report they are down. The RDP port seems to go and down. During a period when PRTG is reporting that it is up, you still cannot RDP to it.

We have been on site and we can get the login screen to appear, but once we switch user the screen goes blank and no video signal.

We have contacted Dell and we have run DSET reports and hardware diagnostics on the machine, but no hardware failures. We have updated all firmware for the Dell but still cannot locate the problem.

System event logs don't show any signs of trouble until the crash actually happens.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: Have you investigated with the PERC patrol read (try disabling it for some time to verify whether it may impact your system) ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this link for other troubleshooting steps from Microsoft:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2015/04/03/server-hungbecoming-unresponsive/

Also, I found this one, but not sure that it is relevant to your particular case: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2897632/logon-screen-turns-black-in-windows-8-1-or-windows-server-2012-r2